# Error while deleting folder

Tags: 18.04

I have a question about deleting a folder on Ubuntu 18.04 TLS.

Why can't I delete this folder?
I have tried to delete with command rm -fr but it didn't work.

[image: Here is the error]

Comment: It says permission denied. Try with root user.

Comment: Thank you very much @P_Yadav . First I gain root permission then I used command rm -R

Comment: but always be careful while using `rm -rf` with root user, because there will be no backup if you deleted wrong files.

Comment: WARNING: A typo when using `rm -rf` can destroy your system. Might there be other, safer ways for you to delete files in /home? (Hint: Yes there are!)